# Zoom control without xml layout?

Tags: android, zooming

I'm trying to get the zoom control on my webview.

I have seen many times this solution :

```
private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);

 FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
    getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    final View zoom = this.objetview.getZoomControls();
    mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
    zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It works pretty well but is it possible to do it without having to use a webview layout in an xml file ? How can I add it to a simple code like this one :

```
public class Affiche extends Activity 
{ 
    public String lien;
```

`@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MyWebView webview = new MyWebView(this);    

    String lien_changed = CreateLien(chapitre , nom_livre_changed); 

    webview.loadUrl(lien_changed);
    setContentView(webview);

 }

class MyWebView extends WebView implements OnGestureListener 
{ ..... // MyWebView to implement Gesture Detector ...`

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. In fact, the code I used is deprecated... This is what works for me now :

```
 webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Thanks !